# What's the best way to sort a two-dimensional matrix by values?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, arrays, matrix

I have a two-dimensional array:

```
function getMatrix(size) {
    var matrix = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        matrix[i] = new Array(size);
    }
    return matrix;
};
```

It is filled with numeric values, so every existing `matrix[i][j]` is a `Number`. What is the best way to get a sequence of `i` and `j` pairs that will correspond to a seqence of highest to lowest values in the matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd create a class that has attributes `i`, `j` and `value`. Create an object for each value in the matrix by filling i, j and the matrix value into this object. Put all objects in a list and sort the list with `list.sort(sortFunction)` and a self-defined `sortFunction` that sorts the list by `object.value`.

Then print the `(i,j)` pairs in the sorted list.